# Query that return children, and parent with children

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains articles. Some articles are part of a parent article.

This is my model:

```
article_id | parent_article_id | title
--------------------------------------
61         | 0                 | ...
62         | 61                | ...
43         | 61                | ...
48         | 61                | ...
```

**EXAMPLE 1:**

If I select a parent article (let's say `article_id` 61) i want to return `article_id` 62, 43 and 48. In other words, find all of the child articles.

I was able to create a successful query:

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.title
FROM article a
WHERE a.parent_article_id = 61
```

**EXAMPLE 2:**

This is where I get stuck:

I kind of want to do the reverse. For example, if i select a child article (let's say `article_id` 43), i want to return `article_id` 61, 62, 48. In other words, if i select a child article, then return the parent article (61) and all of the children (62, 48). i don't need to return the child `article_id` 43..

How do i create 1 query for both examples ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as:

```
select a.article_id, a.title
from article a
where a.parent_article_id = (select a2.parent_article_id 
                             from article a2
                             where a2.article_id = 43
                            ) or
      a.article_id = (select a2.parent_article_id 
                      from article a2
                      where a2.article_id = 43
                     );
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
select a.*
from article a join
     article a43
     on a43.article_id = 43 and
        a43.parent_article_id in (a.parent_article_id, a.article_id);
```

The performance of the first version might be better with the right indexes.

Comment: if i select article_id 61, i get all of the articles... I need to do a query that complies with both examples. I will never hard code the number 43... that number was just an example

Comment: @Marco . . . Your specific question is "For example, if i select article_id 43".  If you have a different question, please ask *another* question.

Comment: sorry for that, english is not my first language. I want to do just 1 query for both examples.

Comment: I edited my question so hopefully it's clearer. Again, sorry for that... english is not my first language

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your requirement is to look for parents, siblings and children.
For item 61 (example 1), there is no parent and hence no siblings. Therefore you are looking for children only.
For item 43 (example 2), there is parent and siblings. Item 43 does not have children.  The following is modified from Gordon Linoff's solution (using item 43 as an example).  It should also work for item 61.

```
select a.article_id, a.title
from article a
where 

      a.article_id = (select a2.parent_article_id 
                             from article a2
                             where a2.article_id = 43
                            )  -- find parents
      or  

      (a.parent_article_id = (select a2.parent_article_id 
                      from article a2
                      where a2.article_id = 43)
        and a.article_id <> 43 )  -- find siblings
      or
      a.parent_article_id = 43 -- find children
```

Comment: @Marco you should try to understand the logic and modify it to suit your needs.  Don't expect you can just copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the given article's parent article and all the children of the parent (except the given article), then the following query will work:

```
select article_id 
from article 
where (
    parent_article_id = 
      (select parent_article_id from article where article_id = 43)
    or article_id = 
      (select parent_article_id from article where article_id = 43)
  ) 
  and article_id != 43;
```

The output of this will be:

```
+------------+
| article_id |
+------------+
|         61 |
|         62 |
|         48 |
+------------+
```